# Loops from R to Python

Tags: python, r, loops

I wrote this code in R but I'd like to know how to do the same iteration in python:

```
k=1
while(k<=nrow(df)){
  i=0
  while(df$Player[k]==df$Player[k+i]) {
    if (k==(k+i)) df$mintot[k+i]=0
    else df$mintot[k+i]=sum(df$MIN[k:(k+i-1)])
    for(j in 16:78){
      df[(k+i),(j+65)]=sum(df[(k:(k+i-1)),j])/df$mintot[k+i]
    }
    i=i+1
  }
  k=k+i
  if(k%%10==0) print(k)
}
```

Practically I'm calculating a sort of moving average, from the first observation of a player till the penultimate one. And I repeat these for more variables (hence the for loop j in 16:78)

Comment: `if (k==(k+i)) df$mintot[k+i]=0` is equivalent to `if (i==0) df$mintot[k] <- 0`; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad

Comment: Have you made an attempt to translate the code to python yourself already?

Comment: Your question may be salvageable if you show some of your own efforts to translate the code snippet and what problems you got. Otherwise I fear it will be closed as "too broad". I will not vote to close right now because I want to give you the chance to improve the question - since you are relatively new around here and may not know all the rules.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the stated purpose of the `converters` tag, so I removed that tag. Please look at the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm pretty sure the question was about whether there is an automated tool that could do the translation. I would argue that it's not entirely off -topic and I don't know of a better tag for that specific purpose.

To answer the question, there is currently no translation tool for Python and R. I believe PolYamoR was a project that was trying to do that but it was quickly aborted and has been dead for 3 years.

Comment: @Syncrossus Nothing about the question asked for an automated tool. It is unlikely that OP read that "Converters can change data from one type to another, translate data based on cultural information, or modify other aspects of presentation" and decided that this was a good description of the problem they faced. Chances are they merely like the *name* of the tag and decided to use it because there problem had something to do with the much broader problem of converting code from something to something else.

Comment: @JohnColeman, my bad, I haven't read properly the description, I'm sorry. Still you're making much ado about nothing

Comment: @RiccardoTornaghi I didn't downvote you or anything, but you are a new user who made the extremely common mistake of engaging in tag-inflation, so I just pointed it out. My original edit and comment took me about 30 seconds -- before others decided to make much ado about little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a literal translation in Python of your code.

```
    k=1
    while k<= len(df):
        i=0
        while df['Player'].iloc[k]==df['Player'].iloc[k+i]:
            if k==(k+i):
                df['mintot'].iloc[k+i]=0
            else:
                df['mintot'].iloc[k+i] = sum(df['MIN'].iloc[k:(k+i-1)])
            for j in range(16,78):
                df.loc[(k+i)].values[j+65]=sum(df.loc[k:(k+i-1)].values[j])/df['mintot'].iloc[k+i]

        i=i+1
        k=k+i
        if k%10==0:
            print(k)
```

Nevertheless, without any sample data is impossible to test so I can't guarantee it will work 100% on your data. 
**If it works, you should double-check the correctness of the indexing.**
e.g. here `df[(k:(k+i-1)),j]` on the first iteration when k=1 and i=0 you are querying the df[1:0,0] which in python/pandas is not possible.